Jquery Ajax Post Alert is Noth Showing the Returned Data, it is showing the current page source
I am not getting the expected result when trying to post a form using ajax.
I have a simple form. I also have a jquery script to submit the form so I can try to pre-validate a captcha text box before submitting the form.
I know this is something simple, but it's driving me nuts.
What is supposed to do is post to a php page to validate the captcha and other information. Currently for testing, I have my php page just simply output "Test Return Data" then the jquery is supposed to do a simple alert message.
Unfortunately, the return I am getting appears to be the html from the current page not the text being returned.
I do not know if it makes a difference, but I am trying to post to a different page for validation other than what the post in the form says.
If it was working correctly (the way I am trying to get it to work), I would get an alert that says "Test Return Data". My best guess is that I have some kind of syntax error that I am not seeing, or I am going about everything wrong.
I am using jquery-3.7.1.min.js.
What is even more frustrating is that it works on my machine (localhost) in both Edge and Duck-Duck_Go browsers, but not from the server (hosted at HostGator).
Here is a simplified version of the form:
    <form id="LogInForm" name="LogInForm" method="post" action="DoLogin.php" title="Log in to access members only features">

    <label for="UName" id="UNameLbl" class="bregLbl">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="UName" name="UName" />
    
    <label for="PWord" id="PWordLbl" class="bregLbl">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="PWord" name="PWord" />

    <label for="ValidationTxt" id="ValidationTxtLbl" class="bregLbl">Captcha</label>    
    <img src="ValidationImg.php?CB=<?php echo $CB; ?>" id="LogInFormCaptcha" /> &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="ValidationTxt" name="ValidationTxt" />

    <input class="send" type="submit" id="LoginButton" name="LoginButton" value="Log In"  title="Click Here To Log In" />
    
    </form>

Here is my jquery script:
    $("#LogInForm").on("submit", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
      var unameval = $.trim($("#UName").val());
      var pwordval = $.trim($("#PWord").val());
      var valtxtval = $.trim($("#ValidationTxt").val());

   if (unameval.length == 0 || pwordval.length == 0 || valtxtval.length == 0)
   {        
      $("#LogInErrMsgBar").show();
      $("#LogInErrMsgTxt").html("<ul><li>Please complete all form fields</li><ul>");
   }
   else
   {
      var PostData = {uname: unameval,pword: pwordval,valtxt: valtxtval};
      $.post("loginvalidations.php", PostData, function(result){
      alert(result);
      });
   }    
   });

Here is loginvalidations.php:
<?php
echo "Test Return Data";
?>

Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing from when it at my host.It is like the jquery is posting to the same page as the form instead of loginvalidations.php.

Here is what I see from localhost, which is what it's supposed to do.

The whole thing can be seen at https://wvsr.club/login

Are there any errors in the console? This would happen if the error prevented the jQuery code from executing.

Is the $("#LogInForm").on(...) code inside $(document).ready()?

I just tried your live site and got "Test Return Data". This doesn't appear to be reproducible

Well, this is embarrassing...
The problem was not with my code. The problem was actually with my .htaccess file.
I have the entry:
RewriteRule login login.php [L] 

Because the page I was trying to post to is loginvalidations.php and that "login" is the beginning of loginvalidations, the form was indeed posting to itself.
I have remedied that by making sure that I do have a rule to catch loginvalidations before login.
I knew it was going to be something incredibly stupidly simple.
